# Detect map moving in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm wondering if there is any event or method to check if Google map is still moving.

Currently I'm using `drag` event with eventListenerOnce `idle` event, but it's not working as expected. I need constant move checking but when I accelerate map and release mouse button it creates gap between end of drag and map idle moment.

Maybe someone knows some method to do this or workaround.

Cheers.

EDIT:

As of now I figured out something like this, it's working but not perfect.

```
this.changeListener = google.maps.event.addListener(this.map, 'drag', () => {
      let timer;
      this.bubbleHeading();
      google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(this.map, 'dragend', () => {
        timer = setInterval(() => this.bubbleHeading(), 10);
      });
      google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(this.map, 'idle', () => {
        clearInterval(timer);
      });
    });
```

EDIT2:
Here's example of what I want ot archieve:
pointers should be recalculating position during any map move and during mouse hold it works well, but when accelerate and release button it crashes.

Example with `bounds_changed`:
[image]

Example with solution above:
[image]

As you can see, neither first nor second works perfect.

Per this playground: [maps events playground](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events?hl=pl)

```
bounds_changed
```

event is ending before map stops and

```
center_changed & drag
```

works similar - all 3 do nothing when map is in 'free' move.

EDIT3:

Another step forward. In my pointer position calculating function I get rid of `getBounds()` nad `getCenter()` methods because when none of events are fired, bounds and center are not recalculating. On the other hand I noticed that when I'm using `overlay.getProjection().getVisibleRegion()`, values are updating constantly. Result looks pretty smooth:

[image]

Comment: So what do the API docs say about which events exist for the map getting moved? (Because click-drags are only one of several ways in which the map moves, JS itself can trigger map recenters, too)

Comment: What's available in the [reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#Map-Events) docs is what we can only work with. As mike said, there's `bounds_changed` and `center_changed` listener in the map object. Does that not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

### Use `bounds_changed` or `center_changed` event of the `Map` class

in the [Events](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#Map-Events) section of the [Maps Javascript API reference documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map), both of the mentioned events are defined like so:

> **`bounds_changed`** - function()
>
> Arguments:  None
>
> *This event is fired when the viewport bounds have changed.*

> **`center_changed`** - function()
>
> Arguments:  None
>
> *This event is fired when the map center property changes.*

With that said, this should be enough for your use case in detecting movement in the map. Take note though that you would want to use `bounds_changed` if you also want to detect `zoom` changes in your map, because using `center_changed` won't do so because if you zoom in alone, your center does not change.

Here's an example where I set the default event to `bounds_changed` but you can just change it to `center_changed` to test it:

```js
let map;

async function initMap() {
    
    // instantiate the libraries
    const { event } = await google.maps.importLibrary("core");
  const { Map } = await google.maps.importLibrary("maps");
    
    // instantiate the map
  map = new Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
    zoom: 8,
  });
    
  // I set the default event to `bounds_changed`
  // You can try changing it to `center_changed` to test it.
    event.addListener(map, "bounds_changed", function() {
      console.log("Map moved!");
    })

}


initMap();
```

```css
/* 
 * Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div element
 * that contains the map. 
 */
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

/* 
 * Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. 
 */
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
 @license
 Copyright 2019 Google LLC. All Rights Reserved.
 SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
-->
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Default Advanced Marker</title>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css" />
    <script type="module" src="./index.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <!-- prettier-ignore -->
    <script>(g=>{var h,a,k,p="The Google Maps JavaScript API",c="google",l="importLibrary",q="__ib__",m=document,b=window;b=b[c]||(b[c]={});var d=b.maps||(b.maps={}),r=new Set,e=new URLSearchParams,u=()=>h||(h=new Promise(async(f,n)=>{await (a=m.createElement("script"));e.set("libraries",[...r]+"");for(k in g)e.set(k.replace(/[A-Z]/g,t=>"_"+t[0].toLowerCase()),g[k]);e.set("callback",c+".maps."+q);a.src=`https://maps.${c}apis.com/maps/api/js?`+e;d[q]=f;a.onerror=()=>h=n(Error(p+" could not load."));a.nonce=m.querySelector("script[nonce]")?.nonce||"";m.head.append(a)}));d[l]?console.warn(p+" only loads once. Ignoring:",g):d[l]=(f,...n)=>r.add(f)&&u().then(()=>d[l](f,...n))})
        ({key: "AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk", v: "beta"});</script>
  </body>
</html>
<!-- [END maps_advanced_markers_simple] -->
```

I hope this helps!